# How to set the value of value of empty_value field in symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I am making a date field like

```
->add('myDate','date',array(
                'years' => range(date('Y')-50, date('Y')+20),
                'widget' => 'choice',
                'format' => 'yMMMd',
                'days' => array(1),
                'empty_value' => array('year'=>'Year', 'month'=> 'Month'),
                'required' => false
            ))
```

**Edit 1** :

**Qus 1** - How to set the value for year and month option which has empty_text as Year and Month?
**Qus 2** - Is there any way to add extra option in date field for month and year?

**Edit 2** :

Using above paramter I am getting one of field Year like below

```
<select id="" name="" >
<option value="">Year</option>
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
</select>
```

**and i want like below**

```
<select id="" name="" >
<option value="0">Year</option>    //value is 0
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
</select>
```

Apologize for my english

Comment: Are you binding the form to the object? If yes, set the default date on that object.

Comment: what value you want to set in your Year and month fields

Comment: I want to set 0 value because if somebody select only year then the data should come in like '01-00-selected_year'

Comment: Can you show us the controller where you're creating that form ?

Comment: @Touki : I updated my question after your comment..can you please check if that is helpfull

Comment: @Punch23 I meant the *controller* where you're creating `new MyFormType()` and usually `new MyEntity()`

Comment: @Touki I can't disclose the controller code..I am sorry for that. Could you please tell me why do you need controller code

Comment: @Punch23 The form is *most of times* binded to an entity (`$model`). When calling `$this->createForm($type, $model)` So you need to set the value like `$model->setDate(new \Date)`

Comment: @Touki : $model->setDate(new \Date); didn't work..As per Dev, I think i need to find alternate solution..Thanks for your help and all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this -

```
<select id="" name="" >
<option value="0">Year</option>    //value is 0
<option value="1963">1963</option>
<option value="1964">1964</option>
</select>

<select id="" name="" >
<option value="0">Month</option>    //value is 0
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
.
.
.
</select>

<select id="" name="" >
<option value="0">Date</option>    //value is 0
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
.
.
<option value="31">31</option>
</select>
```

Then I think create an object with the default date on object to the value you want. And then bind that object to the form. But I think it's gonna fail because I think it will give error if you try to create date object with date, month or year with value of 0.

Comment: @Dev: so you means to say i can't make what i need as you specify my exact requirement in your answer...

Comment: Yes.
From what i think, by using empty_value. The value in value that represent it will be empty string.

Comment: And if you create date type object. You can't create them with a value 0 for date or month, since it's not valid.

Comment: But mysql can insert data in the format of 2011-00-00... That's why i asked the question. Why can't be set the value of month 0 in symfony2 if user is not selecting the value

Comment: I think data types in programming languages are convertable from one type to another type, that's why php are more strict than mysql, since mysql is only for storing data.
Thank for pointing this out, previously I didn't know that mysql is this linear, I will have to try the same on the postgreous and sqlite too to study about this more.